# Why is my double underscore notation not working with nested pipelines in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv, scikit-learn-pipeline

I'm trying to build a pipeline that contains a pre-processing transformer (it simply removes columns from the data) and an LDA classifier. I wanted to tweak hyperparameters for each, and from looking at other posts and documentation I *should* just need to use `pipelineName__param`, with the double underscore, but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
pp.pprint(sorted(full_pipeline.get_params().keys()))

>>> [...] #lists all possible params for pipeline which I copied into param_grid
```

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

clf_model  = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()

full_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('preprocessing', pp_pipeline),
    ('model', clf_model),
])
    
param_grid = {
    "preprocessing__dropper__drop_attr": [True, False],
    "model__solver": ["svd", "lsqr", "eigen"],
}


search = GridSearchCV(clf_model, param_grid, scoring="f1", return_train_score=True, cv=5, verbose=2, n_jobs=-1)
search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

`pp_pipeline` is a pipeline that contains the transformer that drops columns, and a standard scaler. I have tested this on the `X_train` data alone and it works as expected.

The error the above code block throws up is

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter 'model' for estimator LinearDiscriminantAnalysis().
```

Why is it trying to treat `model` as a parameter and not the pipeline name, even though I've named it appropriately using a double underscore?

I've tried renaming `model` to something else, and even taking the `"model__solver"` out of `param_grid` entirely - if I do that, I instead get the error

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter 'preprocessing' for estimator LinearDiscriminantAnalysis().
```

so I must be missing something key here.

Comment: Note that you are using `lda` as estimator in `GridSearchCV` instead of `full_pipeline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are passing the model, `lda` to grid search, not your pipeline. Your code for the GridSearchCV should be:

```
search = GridSearchCV(full_pipeline, param_grid, 
scoring="f1", return_train_score=True, cv=5, verbose=2, n_jobs=-1
```

Comment: That was a dumb mistake, thanks for the spot!